# Может ли std::vector возвращать коды return`ов?

Tags: c++

Подскажите пожалуйста, может ли std::vector возвращать return`ы ?

Ну для примера:

```
std::vector<int>my_vector;
my_vector.resize(99999999999999999);
```

И чтобы не отлавливать исключения, проанализировать именно код возврата вектора, что память не удалось выделить ?

Comment: нет. и не должен. Используйте исключения.

Comment: Вообще-то, как я понимаю, он просто сгенерирует исключение `bad_alloc`... И вообще — вы в С++, исключения, исключения и исключения, а не коды ошибок...

Comment: @Harry, с return`ами удобнее.

Comment: @Optimus1 Оно может быть удобнее только в тривиальных ситуациях, когда ошибка обрабатывается на месте возникновения.

Comment: @Optimus1 Очень, очень спорное утверждение...

Comment: С return удобнее пока вы не начали писать реальные программы. А когда 80% кода функции у вас будет состоять из проверок результатов вызовов других функций и возврата ошибок, вы очень быстро поменяете свое мнение.

Comment: @Slava, а, что эксепшины проверять не надо ? На них ведь тоже как то нужно реагировать.

Comment: Исключения можно и нужно ловить один раз и только там, где надо. Но самое главное преимущество - если вы исключения вообще не ловите, то ничего плохого не произойдет, в отличие от случая, когда вы игнорируете коды ошибок - вот где засада.

Comment: @Slava, если вы не ловите исключения у вас упадет ваша программа. К примеру тот же bad allocation. А ретурны я всегда обрабатываю. Лично мне с ретурнами удобнее. Весь winapi на ретурнах построен и ничего страшного.

Comment: В том то и дело, что даже если программа упадет, но сообщит, где и какая произошла проблема, это гораздо лучше, чем она упадет позже и совсем в другом месте, лови потом ветра в поле. Если вам удобнее с ретурнами пользуйтесь библиотеками С, там все на ретурнах. Но я боюсь, это "удобство" у вас от недостатка опыта. Как и использование `goto`, тоже ведь удобнее, правда?

Comment: как человек, который вынужден сейчас пользоваться библиотекой, которая построена на return, это бывает очень сложно. Очень. Иногда многоэтажные if, которые все проверяют. И все равно найдется какой то случай, когда ну никак.

Comment: @Slava, использование goto удобнее чего и в каких ситуациях ?

Comment: Ну например, вы не используете RAII и код построен на проверках кодов ошибок, и чтобы не дублировать код очистки ресурсов очень хочется использовать `goto`, Вот вы же использовали `goto` в функции работы с `std::conditional_variable`, вам так удобнее было? Понимаете, какая штука, то что удобнее для написания програм в 10 строк вылазит огромным неудобством при написании реальных в сотни и тысячи строк кода, а то и больше. Но это надо испытать на собственной шкуре, либо поверить на слово.

Comment: @Optimus1, вы правы, исключения в серьезных программах исключительно (да, тавтология) неудобны. Собственно, так же, как и сам С++

Comment: @KoVadim, все равно не понимаю, Вы проверяете return`ы. А исключения не проверяете получается ?

Comment: нет, не проверяю. try-catch присекается при ревью. В коде даже не используются new/delete, а свои аллокаторы. И местами это превращается в такое месиво...

Answer (score 2):

Нет, не может.

Но вы можете написать свои "обертки", например

```
bool resize(vector<int>& v, int N) {
    try {
        v.resize(N);
        return true;
    } catch(...) {}
    return false;
    }
```

Но я бы на вашем месте прислушался к советам выше и классиков - в С++ пользуйтесь исключениями.